# How to resolve 900 key length limit index on the column which have datatype varchar(4096) in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, non-clustered-index

This is the query for creating index
create index idx_ncl_2 on BFPRODATTRASSOCIATION (value,attributeid) include (productid)

Table structure of BFPRODATTRASSOCIATION

```
ProdAttrAssociationId bigint no 8
ProductId             bigint no 8
AttributeId           bigint  no  8
Value                 varchar no 4096
```

I am getting this error:

The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index ‘idx_ncl_2’ has maximum length of 1237 bytes.

I have to create a nonclustered index on this column. Is there any way i can create index for the column which have datatype of varchar and size is greater than 900.

Please suggest.

Comment: the fact you are indexing on a 'value' column seems wrong to me....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - as the error message already clearly states, any index entry cannot be more than 900 bytes long.

You cannot index a varchar(4096) field - period. No way around that - it's a hard SQL Server limit - no way to configure it, change it, make it bigger. See [Books Online - Maximum Size of Index Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241.aspx) for confirmation.

You need to either limit your "value" column to less than 900 bytes, or find another way to store that data - or just not include it in the index. If you only want your "value" field in the index to have a covering index (to be able to satisfy queries from the index entry), you could move the field to be an *included column* in the index - those don't fall under the 900 byte limit.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_ncl_2 
  ON BFPRODATTRASSOCIATION(attributeid) 
  INCLUDE (productid, value)
```

That index should work.

Answer (score 4):

You could [create and index on a computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) that is the hash of the string. See [Hash functions in T-SQL](http://blogs.clarience.com/davide/?p=11) and [Intelligent Database Design Using Hash Keys](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/intelligent-database-design-using-hash-keys/) for some ideas and limitations.

Comment: See also Remus Rusanu's answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8002357/4515489