# SQL server - worth indexing large string keys?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a large string key (varchar(1024)) that I was thinking to be indexed over on SQL server (I want to be able to search over it quickly but also inserts are important). In sql 2008 I don't get a warning for this, but under sql server 2005 it tells me that it exceeds 900 bytes and that inserts/updates with the column over this size will be dropped (or something in that area)

What are my alternatives if I would want to index on this large column ? I don't know if it would worth it if I could anyway.

Comment: You question isn't particularly useful without context.  Why do you think you need an index?  How would you use it?

Comment: see comment bellow Remus Rusanu

Comment: anyone know if it'd be useful to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx if you must use long strings for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An index with all the keys near 900 bytes would be very large and very deep (very few keys per page result in very tall B-Trees).

It depends on how you plan to **query** the values. An index is useful in several cases:

- when a value is probed. This is the most typical use, is when an exact value is searched in the table. Typical examples are `WHERE column='ABC'` or a join condition `ON a.column = B.someothercolumn`.
- when a range is scanned. This is also fairly typical when a *range* of values is searched in the table. Besides the obvious example of `WHERE column BETWEEN 'ABC' AND 'DEF'` there are other less obvious examples, like a partial match: `WHERE column LIKE 'ABC%'`.
- an ordering requirement. This use is less known, but indexes can help a query that has an explicit `ORDER BY column` requirement to avoid a stop-and-go sort, and also can help certain hidden sort requirement, like a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column)`.

So, why do you need the index for? What kind of queries would use it?

For range scans and for ordering requirements there is no other solution but to have the index, and you will have to weigh the cost of the index vs. the benefits.

For probes you can, potentially, use hash to avoid indexing a very large column. Create a persisted computed column as `column_checksum = CHECKSUM(column)` and then index on that column. Queries have to be rewritten to use `WHERE column_checksum = CHECKSUM('ABC') AND column='ABC'`. Careful consideration would have to be given to weighing the advantage of a narrow index (32 bit checksum) vs. the disadvantages of collision double-check and lack of range scan and order capabilities.

*after the comment*

I once had a similar problem and I used a hash column. The value was too large to index (>1K) and I also needed to convert the value into an ID to store (basically, a dictionary). Something along the lines:

```
create table values_dictionary (
  id int not null identity(1,1),
  value varchar(8000) not null,
  value_hash = checksum(value) persisted,
  constraint pk_values_dictionary_id
     primary key nonclustered (id));
create unique clustered index cdx_values_dictionary_checksum on (value_hash, id);
go

create procedure usp_get_or_create_value_id (
   @value varchar(8000),
   @id int output)
begin
   declare @hash = CHECKSUM(@value);
   set @id = NULL;
   select @id = id
      from table
      where value_hash = @hash
      and value = @value;
  if @id is null
  begin
      insert into values_dictionary (value)
        values (@value);
      set @id = scope_identity();
  end
end
```

In this case the dictionary table is organized as a clustered index on the `values_hash` column which groups all the colliding hash values together. The `id` column is added to make the clustered index unique, avoiding the need for a [hidden uniqueifier column](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/). This structure makes the lookup for `@value` as efficient as possible, w/o a hugely inefficient index on `value` and bypassing the 900 character limitation. The primary key on `id` is non-clustered which means that looking up the `value` from and `id` incurs the overhead of one extra probe in the clustered index.

Not sure if this answers your problem, you obviously know more about your actual scenarios than I do. Also, the code does not handle error conditions and can actually insert duplicate @value entries, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Remus. That actually makes sense. I think I am mainly using this column at inserts for locating if it's already there (and it's associated row unique id) so that I can reference that column's id as foreign key in another table. That makes sense :-) ? So mainly for case described: WHERE column='ABC'

Comment: +1, I thought about adding an index on a hash column, but wondered what to do with collisions, never thought about having an index on BOTH the hash column and id column.

Answer (score 2):

[General Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191195.aspx)

> When you design an index consider the following column guidelines:
>
> - Keep the length of the index key short for clustered indexes. Additionally, clustered indexes benefit from being created on unique
>     or nonnull columns. For more information, see Clustered Index Design
>     Guidelines.
> - Columns that are of the ntext, text, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) data types cannot be specified as
>     index key columns. However, varchar(max), nvarchar(max),
>     varbinary(max), and xml data types can participate in a nonclustered
>     index as nonkey index columns. For more information, see Index with
>     Included Columns.
> - Examine data distribution in the column. Frequently, a long-running query is caused by indexing a column with few unique values, or by
>     performing a join on such a column. This is a fundamental problem with
>     the data and query, and generally cannot be resolved without
>     identifying this situation. For example, a physical telephone
>     directory sorted alphabetically on last name will not expedite
>     locating a person if all people in the city are named Smith or Jones

Comment: So basically in my case where I have this large varchar column, I would just have to stick in not using an index at all ? I also so an example on the link provided:
CREATE INDEX IX_Address_PostalCode
ON Person.Address (PostalCode)
INCLUDE (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, StateProvinceID); In provided example it seems that only PostalCode counts on index size. Does this help performance at all when querying over AddressLine1 column (e.g.  "WHERE AddressLine1=@Addr1")  ?