# Better string index with Code First

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, architecture

I'm creating a new project and using codefirst with sql server. In this project anyone can search something in our Database looking by string search. I need to perform it. Why should I use do get the user experience better? Thia Database will grow up forever!

Is using CHECKSUM a good way?

Comment: Is the `string` primary key ?

Comment: it can be! But Create a string index in Sql Server I think is not a good idea, is it?

Comment: Depends on how is it accessed, and the length of the strings, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001905/sql-server-worth-indexing-large-string-keys

Comment: https://lucenenet.apache.org/